# WCF Timeouts - How and where to set?

Tags: wcf, timeout, setting

I have a question about timeouts

**Question 1**: Where to set timeout values (on server/service side or client side)?

**Question 2**:

By definition,

The **openTimeout** as the name implies is the amount of time you're willing to wait when you open the connection to your WCF service. Similarly, the **closeTimeout** is the amount of time when you close the connection (dispose the client proxy) that you'll wait before an exception is thrown.

In this case if I set the open and close time out to 10 minutes (00:10:00) what will happen

**A**. when client tries to openconnection? Is service will slowly opens connection?

**B**. when client tries to closeconnection after making calll to a method?  Is this going to close only after 10 min's?

Please help me to understand.

Thanks

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229760/timeouts-wcf-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The timeout is set on the side which is establishing the communication. In your example I believe it would be the client side.
2. A) The client will have 10 minutes to attempt to establish a connection before it throws an error.
3. B) The client will have 10 minutes to close the established connection before it throws an error.

Comment: You can set timeouts on both sides. I will also advise OP to call Close explicitly to free the resources asap, before the timeout kicks in.

Comment: Why would you need to set the time-out on both sides?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please take a look at my other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273872/wcf-timeout-error-even-after-increasing-the-values

Comment: @DeviantSeev for example when service returns a callback to the client

Comment: @oleksii can you provide an example of when you would do it this way as opposed to just relying on the timeout presets of the caller? (In this case the client) I am probably missing something but if you set the sendTimeout on the client then shouldn't the sendTimeout be what dictates how long the server has to respond to the client before the  request is aborted?

Comment: @DeviantSeev yeah that's correct for the most common use of WCF services. Although there some situations when I can define a separate callback interface, for example a client asks for a long runing operation to be completed on the service. Instead of blocking and waiting for the operation to complete on the service, a client returns immediately and provide the service with a return address, binding and contract - the callback. So once the service has finished the work it can send the results back to the original caller. This is when I need to define the timeouts for the callback operations.

Comment: @oleksii oh ok that sounds interesting. Never encountered that one before. :)