# Create separate HTML page for each item (product list) using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

I am trying to display a list of products available on a public-facing website. When a user clicks on a product, I want to display details about that product.

I saw some websites (even Stack Overflow) that display a separate page for each thread. I know this website uses MVC, but I am using a basic ASP.NET web application.

I want do the samething for my product details page. For example, 
www.mywebsite.com/product-ipod.html or www.mywebsite.com/product-ipod

Can anyone tell me how to do that using ASP.NET?

Other existing samples,

[WCF Timeout Error - Even after increasing the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273872/wcf-timeout-error-even-after-increasing-the-values)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/grid-samples

http://www.city-data.com/forum/austin/1316155-how-many-flee-austin-because-allergies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Routing. [Read this article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply.I still have doubt. I am displaying the products in well formatted grid. In each html table title I am displaying the 'product  title' and hyperlink (which is an external vendor website). sample: http://tinyurl.com/dkmwd

My scenario is not like 
http://www.store.com/products.aspx?category=books
http://www.store.com/products.aspx?category=DVDs

mine is,
http://www.demo.com/ (default.aspx)

Can you help?

Comment: I got the answer for my question. Thanks