# TimeoutException for WCF Method call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Client(Windows Service) which makes a call to a WCF Service which is causing the client to block indefinitely and finally timeout though the task is completed at the service side. This uses a Binary Delegation binding and the method requires impersonation. I am attaching the Client and Service log for reference.

Two questions:

1. What are the causes of getting the call blocked at the service
2. Any suggestions to trace the message traffic between the client and
   service

Comment: Please Take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981475/wcf-timeout-exception-detailed-investigation

Comment: For your second question you can turn on wcf tracing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing

Comment: Links to logs: \https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwuTSTC_hnPVVnlhMHlWOHM3d0U

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwuTSTC_hnPVNlRDdFR6UkVuT3M

Comment: No one is going to download your logs from Google Drive.  Embed the parts of importance here in your question

Comment: I could see the below message at server 
after process action<Description>Sent a message over a channel.</Description> However client is still waiting for the response message