# connectionManagement element

Tags: c#, wcf

I had some problems with my WCF timing out.

I read [WCF timeout exception detailed investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981475/wcf-timeout-exception-detailed-investigation) and added this to my web.config:

```
<system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add maxconnection = "100" address ="*" />
</connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Since it already was on my WCF side web.config, I added it to my client side web.config (they are on seperate machines).

My question is: Should this element be applied to the client side? Or am I doind it wrong? Couldnt really catch that from the above thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about your question, and reading the MSDN library here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc(v=vs.110).aspx  , I've found:

> The connectionManagement element defines the maximum number of
>   connections **to a server** or group of servers.

I can understand that is a client configuration, specially seeing the example:

> The following code example configures an application to use four
>   connections to the server www.contoso.com and two connections **to all
>   other servers.**

```
<connectionManagement>
      <add address="http://www.contoso.com" maxconnection="4" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection="2" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Hope it helps.