# Channel time out error when trying to invoke a webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have got this error while invoking

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9970702. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I have seen this in SO
[WCF stops responding after about 10 or so calls (throttling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739312/c-wcf-wcf-stops-responding-after-about-10-or-so-calls-throttling)

But i dont know where i have to implement this..Whether in my webconfig file or webservice config file..Any suggestion?

EDIT(1):

This is my webconfig file

```
<system.serviceModel>
                <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSL" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="UserNameTokenOverSSLBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSBinaryCertReliable" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="true" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="WSUserNameReliable" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="true" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="WSBinaryCert" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="WSUserName" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/WsBinaryCertReliable"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSBinaryCertReliable"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="WSBinaryCertReliable">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="https://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/BinaryCertTokenOverSSL"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BinaryCertTokenOverSSL"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSL" />
            <endpoint address="http://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/WSUserNameReliable"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSUserNameReliable"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="WSUserNameReliable">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/WSBinaryCert"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSBinaryCert"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="WSBinaryCert">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/WSUserName"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSUserName"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="WSUserName">
                <identity>
                    <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="https://XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com/VWWebservice/VWSecurityServices.svc/UserNameTokenOverSSL"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UserNameTokenOverSSLBinding"
                contract="IVWSecurityServices" name="UserNameTokenOverSSLBinding" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

and this is my webservice config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="sslOffloadedHttpsTransport" type="XXX.VW.Web.Services.CustomBinding.SSLOffloadedHttpsTransportElement, XXX.VW.RT.WebServices.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="e-ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="Online" />
            </clientCertificate>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="XXXvm134.rsimail.rsil.XXX.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="XXX.VW.RT.VWCustomUserValidator,XXX.VW.RT.Library" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="UserNameTokenOverSSLBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSLBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
         <binding name="Vw30BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
          <binding name="Vw30netTcpHABinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
            <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </binaryMessageEncoding>
            <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999998" connectionBufferSize="8192" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" channelInitializationTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="99999998" maxPendingConnections="20" maxOutputDelay="00:00:00.2000000" maxPendingAccepts="5" transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="20" portSharingEnabled="false" teredoEnabled="false">
            <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" leaseTimeout="00:00:02" idleTimeout="00:02:00" maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="20" />
            </tcpTransport>
            </binding>
            <binding name="Vw30HttpHABinding">
            <textMessageEncoding />
            <httpTransport keepAliveEnabled="false">
            </httpTransport>
        </binding> 

        <binding name="UserNameTokenOverSSLOffloaderBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <sslOffloadedHttpsTransport />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BinaryCertTokenOverSSLOffloaderBinding">
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <sslOffloadedHttpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Vw30netTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSUserNameBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSBinaryCertBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" establishSecurityContext="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSUserNameReliableBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="true">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WsBinaryCertReliableBinding" transactionFlow="true">
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
          <security>
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services configSource="Web.Services.config" />    
    <!--Should be uncommented when webservices are consumed through SSL Offloaders, and the application pool should be set to use .NET framework 4.0. -->
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/> -->
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please share the pertinent config bits for both your service and its client.

Comment: In the configs above, which service is giving you the problem?

Comment: i dont know about that..am new to webservices

Comment: Then you'll need to debug to see which service is being called when that error is raised.

Comment: while invoking in webservice studio i have got this error..but before that i have used this code so many times it dint give this error..now its giving everytime while invoking...dont know why

Comment: ok thats fine..what i have to do to rectify this

Comment: See my answer below for stuff to try.  Without more info, not sure i can help any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This generally comes down to sessions and throttling

Prior to .NET 4 the default maximum number of concurrent sessions was 10. This means that the 11th concurrent session waits for one of the others to go away and will eventually hit the clients send timeout (which defaults to 1 minute)

After .NET 4 the default is 100 x number of processors (cores) so is much less likely to be hit

You have 3 options:

1. Increase the session throttle http://www.codegain.com/articles/wcf/security/wcf-service-throttling-behavior.aspx
2. Shut down the existing sessions more quickly (ensuring you call Close on the proxy promptly)
3. Increase the send timeout in the client

Comment: The session is kept alive until either the client closes their proxy or the service times out the session via the receiveTimeout. If the client closes their proxy then it will allow another session to start without increasing the throttle

Answer (score 1):

General advice, since it's difficult to tell which service is causing your error:

Make sure that your timeout values match in the configs for the service and the client.

This is a very common issue with folks new to web services.  If you increase one value, it's usually a good idea to increase the matching value on the other end.

So, go make sure all the timeout values match on both service and client for all your binding behaviors and give it another shot.

If that doesn't work, try increasing ALL your values by adding in a zero and give it a shot.  If that works, then begin reducing timeouts until you find the one that's cause the problem, and then just adjust it.

That's a long way to go around the problem, but since you don't know which service is causing issues, it might be your best bet.

Comment: All of the timeouts are asymmetric and mean different things between the client and service. The sendTimeout in the client is how long they will wait for the response. The receiveTimeout in the client matters if they are doing duplex messaging. The sendTimeout in the service matters if they are in turn calling other services and the receiveTimeout determines the how long the service will wait before it decides a client has gone away for session based conversations. So really its better that people use the timeouts correctly rather than just duplicating them

Comment: I agree in general, but in a case like this, where he's new to WCF and doesn't know where his problem is, this is a potential way to get things working.  It's a scattershot approach, but I've seen it work before.

Comment: have a doubt..i have a webservice..how to check my webservice is asp.net webservice or wcf webservice?

Comment: What's the address of the service?  If it ends in .asmx it's an ASP.Net web service.  If it ends in .svc it's WCF.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

May be u have not close the object after calling services.

**Example:**

WCFServices.Module1 objWCFServ=new WCFServices.Module1();
DataSet ds=obj.MethodName(param1,param2);
...
....

objWCFServ.Close();
objWCFServ=null;